# How do I change the display name of an iCalendar in Outlook?

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

How do I change the display name of an iCalendar in Outlook 2010? I tried to use `X-WR-CALNAME: myName`, but it did not take. Outlook used the filename, instead.

[image: import iCal in Outlook]

Here is a part of iCal file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:myProdId
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:myName
X-WR-TIMEZONE;VALUE=TEXT:US/Pacific
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20110915T060000
DTEND:20110915T060000
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested with Outlook 2007 and it does take the calendar name from `X-WR-CALNAME`. Tested multiple times with different filenames and the result was always the same. Regardless of the file name, the calendar name was the same as specified by `X-WR-CALNAME`.

Please make sure your calendar complies with [the iCalendar specification](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) and passes [validation](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icalendar-validator).

When testing, please note that Outlook caches the calendars and it is difficult to force Outlook to reload the calendar to make sure your changes have taken effect. I've noticed that the simplest way is just to rename the file and resubscribe it into Outlook. If you recently added the name tag, it may well be Outlook is just displaying the cached version, not the most recent one.

Comment: Further research revealed, that the problem is actually with Outlook. If using the http protocol to subscribe the calendar `http://mydomain/mycalendar.ics`Outlook will NOT show the correct calendar name, but the filename. But if the address is given with webcal protocol `webcal://mydomain/mycalendar.ics` everything works well.