# How to Set a Title/Description for a Subscription Calendar (webcal:// ICS file)

Tags: calendar, subscription, icalendar

I have a calendar app for which I provide subscriptions by linking client using the "webcal://" protocol.  It's working quite nicely.  What I'd like to know is if there is a way title it in the receiving calendar application, such as Outlook, iPhone, Google, etc?

Currently, when loaded into Outlook it is displayed as the name of the web script from which it came.  For instance if the script is (using ColdFusion) Create_ICS_File.cfm then Outlook shows it as "Create_ICS_File in Internet Calendars".

On the iPhone it shows up in Calendar as the full web address including URL variables.  For example: mywebsite.com/Create_ICS_File.cfm?calid=4329-32

Is the a way, in the ICS file or otherwise, to set a title on these subscriptions?

Comment: Did you resolve this at all? If you did, can you please share your solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using the X-WR-CALNAME - The display name of the calendar
should do the trick

See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Calendar_extensions.

See also 
[How do I change the display name of an iCalendar in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360866/how-do-i-change-the-display-name-of-an-icalendar-in-outlook)