# iOS Subscribing to webcal calendars

Tags: ios, calendar, ekeventstore, webcal

I am trying to programmatically subscribe to a calendar. I got fairly close with my two liner, but now I am having issues with the name. I would like the notification to say something more user friendly such as "School Calendar" instead of the URL. Any recommendations for going about this?

```
NSString *url = @"webcal://ems.gonzaga.edu/MasterCalendar/iCalFeed.aspx?data=f1bM4GJyEC5fBiWFbx2IWQ%3d%3d";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

[image]

Comment: related question (but no answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341006/how-to-set-a-title-description-for-a-subscription-calendar-webcal-ics-file

Comment: thank you. I'll keep my eye on that one too

Answer (score 1):

If you control both sides of this then you can use the `X-WR-CALNAME` field in your ICS file to provide a friendly name, I'm not aware of a way to do this purely on the client though.